# Form validation with jQuery (without validation.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform a form validation with jQuery. Right now I'm using HTML5 'required' inside the input tag, and this code of jQuery for the validation:

jQuery:

```
$("#register").click(function() {

    $("#register input").each(function() {
        $(this).css('border','none');
        if(!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).css('border','solid 1px red');
        }
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($(this).val())){
            $(this).css('border','solid 1px red');
        }
    });
```

When using IE9, there is no support in HTML5 'required', so although the script is working, it's still running the input action .php file. I'll be happy to know can I fix it using the existing code and without using validate.js or other external files.

HTML5:

```
<form id="register" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
<p><label>First name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="true" /></p>
<p><label>Last name</label><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required="true" /></p>
<p><label>Email</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="true" /></p>
<p>
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input id="area-code" type="text" name="code" maxlength="3" required="true" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" />
    <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" required="true" maxlength="17" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" />

</p>
<input type="submit" value="GET BONUS NOW" id="submit-btn" />
<?php include 'form.php';?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change from validation from `click` event to [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$("#register").submit(function() {
```

And modify your code to look for errors with some boolean flag and return `false` if errors was found:

```
var errors = false;
$("#register input").each(function() {

    $(this).css('border','none');
    if(!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).css('border','solid 1px red');
        errors = true;
    }
    var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
    if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($(this).val())){
        $(this).css('border','solid 1px red');
        errors = true;
    }
});
if( errors ) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and helping me. This code is working, but now i'd like to know two things: (1) It's working only on click event, not on submit event (tried both). (2) On IE9, I can type invalid email address.

Comment: 1. It should work only on submit event. Look if `register` ID is unique on HTML and it's applied to `<form>` element. 2. That's trange, are you sure your regexp is correct?

Comment: turns out it's not working in submit event because of 'required' inside the input tag. It was nice of I could use both of them. Why not use the click event...?

Comment: You can use `click` on form but it's useless as for me as form isn't block element or something better to use submit event that will work on Enter keydown event for example or click on submit.